# Calculate the Running Total Balance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have closing balance of last month and I want to calculate running balances per day based on the closing balance of last month. What I tried is below

```
DECLARE @TestTable TABLE
(
  id int,
  somedate date,
  Credit   INT,
  Debit INT
)

DECLARE @LastMothClosing INT=2000
insert into @TestTable values
(1,     '01/Jan/20',   1000,100),
(2,     '02/Jan/20',   0,0),
(3,     '03/Jan/20',   500,500),
(4,     '04/Jan/20',   1000,200),
(5,     '05/Jan/20',   100,50)

select id,
       somedate,
       Credit,
       Debit,
      (Credit-Debit)+ (SUM(@LastMothClosing) over(order by somedate rows unbounded preceding)) as runningtotal
from @TestTable
```

I want to add Closing Balance of previous day to credit amount of next day and then it should subtract from Debit amount to get balance and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you were summing the wrong value. Try the following:

```
select id
  , SomeDate
  , Credit
  , Debit
  , @LastMothClosing + sum(Credit-Debit) over (order by somedate rows unbounded preceding) as RunningTotal
from @TestTable;
```

Which gives:

```
id  SomeDate    Credit  Debit   RunningTotal
--------------------------------------------
1   2020-01-01  1000    100     2900
2   2020-01-02  0       0       2900
3   2020-01-03  500     500     2900
4   2020-01-04  1000    200     3700
5   2020-01-05  100     50      3750
```